# Apache HTTPD "sites/mods-enabled/available" configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I've recently moved from the default Ubuntu/Debian `apache2` packages to installing the Apache HTTPD from the official tarballs. I have everything working fine, but I wanted to know if there's any easy way to change to use the `sites-*` and `mods-*` folder structure for enabling and disabling vhosts/mods rather than manually specifying them in `httpd.conf`. Are there any scripts or configuration files that do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy over your full apache2 directory from  your Debuntu package. There's no special fu -- it's just the way the config includes are set up which allows that structure to function.